# Is it possible to "extend" IntelliJ such that I can open the current file in VIM

Tags: vim, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ for most of my Java programming, but every once in a while I need to make certain changes which are much easier done in VIM.

Thus, the question:

While I'm editing a file in IntelliJ, it is somehow possible to tell IntelliJ to start VIM with the same file that is currently under cursor.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Absolutely!

Go to `File -> Settings -> External Tools` and add a new one.

Program and Working Directory fields should be self-explanatory. The parameter field should be $FilePath$. Click the Insert macro button to see more token values that you could use.

You can also bind keyboard shortcuts to the external tools you define.

See [the help page on configuring third party tools](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-third-party-tools.html) for more info.

Also, see the answers below with helpful screenshots for [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14645039/3104542) or [Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8964037/3104542).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. VIM complains that it requires a terminal. I need VIM to open in a separate window, not within IntelliJ 'RUN' window.

Comment: What about if the command is to launch your terminal. (e.g. /usr/bin/terminator or /usr/bin/gnome-terminal) and the params are -e 'vim $FilePath$' ?

Comment: Alternatively, if you use gvim, just put gvim in as the program instead of vim.

Comment: Minor update: It's now `File --> Settings --> Tools --> External Tools`

Answer (score 17):

Even though the original question is about VIM, I'd like to share my settings for GVIM. Especially useful is the parameter used to take it to the current line.

[image]

I find it useful to have Gvim open up the file AND take me to the current line. This is done using the following parameters: `+$LineNumber$ $FilePath$`.

When executed, Gvim should open up and take you to the line you were at in Intellij.

Comment: Nice answer ~ I use `Open With` as my group.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to set this up with the Homebrew version of MacVim (i.e. the **mvim** command) on Intellij IDEA 14.

- Go to **Preferences->Tools->External Tools** and click the plus symbol.

[image: Screenshot of settings window]

- Set up the new tool with these parameters

**Program:**

```
/usr/local/bin/mvim
```

**Parameters:**

```
+"silent! "$LineNumber$"|norm! zz" $FilePath$
```

**Working Directory:**

```
$SourcepathEntry$
```

[image: Screenshot of external editor config tool]

Answer (score 5):

For macOS 10.12+ users, If you want to open it in **iTerm2**, here is a latest solution:

```
#!/bin/sh

vim="vim $1"
osascript -e "
tell application \"iTerm\"
    set myterm to (create window with default profile)
    tell myterm
        activate current session
        launch session \"Default Session\"
        tell the current session
            write text \"$vim\"
       end tell
   end tell
end tell
"
```

Date: Apr 5, 2018
iTerm2: 3.1.5
IntelliJ IDEA: 2018.1
[https://gist.github.com/backslash112/open_vim_in_iterm.sh](https://gist.github.com/backslash112/67ba9a8dcef114930abc3afa1338c49d)

Answer (score 3):

This was somewhat more involved on the Mac OS X (Lion), especially if you'd like to use Terminal.app

The only difference on Linux is the shell script would be much simpler... (really it'd be simple to not even use a shell script for this on Linux, with a terminal that accepts the -e argument!)

Here's my working solution:

```
#! /bin/sh
vim="vim $1"

osascript -e "tell app \"Terminal\"
    activate
    do script \"$vim\"
end tell"
```

[image: Settings for JetBrains IDE's (ie. IntelliJ, WebStorm, etc...)]

Answer (score 1):

I am using these parametrs for launching vim: `+$LineNumber$  --remote-tab-silent "$FilePath$"`. It allows you to open each new file in vim's tabs. Works fine)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to **Settings -> Tools -> External Tools**
2. Click the **+** to add a tool.
3. Here are the settings I use:

   - Name: Vim
   - Program: `/usr/bin/gvim`
   - Arguments: `--servername $ProjectFileDir$ --remote "+call cursor($LineNumber$,$ColumnNumber$)" $FileDir$/$FileName$`
   - Working directory: `$ProjectFileDir$`

I turn off "Open console for tool output".

The arguments will use Vim in client-server mode, so if you jump to Vim from IntelliJ in the same project dir multiple times, the existing Vim instance will be reused, and they will also place the cursor in Vim exactly where it is in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Try out the VIM Plugin, http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=164

I have experienced some bugs but for the most part it works.

Comment: I'm aware of vim plugin. What I want is for IntelliJ to start an external VIM process opened with a file I had under cursor.

Comment: I feel like the Vim Plugin does more for marketing purposes (getting VIM users to try their product) then it does for the developer.  IMHO running around with a gimped Vim not only hurts my brain, it also seems to make the JetBrains experience lesser (because lot's of things need to change when using the Vim plugin).  It just isn't polished, and incomplete/buggy/unpolished development tools will do more to decrease performance then increase.  Opting to use Vim when the editing challenge suits it, and learning the polished version of the IDE is a much better option in my book.

Comment: I've gotten pretty frustrated with IdeaVim.  I'm switching back to Vim